# Layouttrouble extending tablerow and inflating xml tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm pretty close to go for a LinearLayout alternative, but its kind of irritating not getting this right. To get most flexibility out of things I've defined a TableLayout xml with only a row header defined. Next I've generated a seperate TableRow xml defining the "row template". In Javacode I've subclassed TableRow and in the constructor i inflate the tablerow template to attach to the root (the subclassed class).

Well, good so far. When the table is populated the headerrow is ok, but the other rows are NOT. It seems like they are laid out in a different way, the two columns is not filling the whole width as expected and the the coluomns is therefore not aligned correctly to each other.

Anyone who can shed some light on this one? I've tried a lot of solutions, but nothing makes it work.

The tablelayout with header row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/zone_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:clipToPadding="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:background="#ffcccccc"
                    android:text="Zonename"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:background="#ffcccc00"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Antall"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

The "other" inflated row

```
    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zonetablerow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zonerow_name"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="#ffcccccc"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zonerow_invcount"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#ffcccc00"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</TableRow>
```

Class extending TableRow

```
    public class ZoneRow extends TableRow {
    private ZoneInventoryDAO dao = null;
    private int inventoryCount = 0;

    public ZoneRow(Context ctx, ZoneInventoryDAO dao) {
        this(ctx, dao, 0);
    }

    public ZoneRow(Context ctx, ZoneInventoryDAO dao, int inventoryCount) {
        super(ctx);
        setWeightSum(1.0f);
        this.dao = dao;
        this.inventoryCount = inventoryCount;
        doLayout();
    }

    private void doLayout() {
        // XML layouten settes med zonerow som parent (se:
        // http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zonerow,
                this, true);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zonerow_name);
        TextView cnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zonerow_invcount);

        t.setText(dao.getZoneAlias());
        cnt.setText(String.valueOf(inventoryCount));

    }

    public void incInventory() {
        inventoryCount++;
    }

    public ZoneInventoryDAO getDAO() {
        return dao;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is that you are extending tablerow and creating an instance of that object. This will cause a table row to be created. Then you are inflating another tablerow which is for some reason interacting with the first. For a quick fix try adding something like table.setColumnStretchable(0, true);

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  I fixed it by not doing that - specifically by not subclassing TableRow, but just instantiating them in code and applying whatever I needed to them by hand. You can do this by encapsulating instead.  Have some record that has ZoneInventoryDAO, inventoryCount, and tableRow, which points to the corresponding TableRow instance.  Just instantiate TableRow with an inflation:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_table, null); // etc
...
for (//each data item//) {
  TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_table_row, null);
  TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.table_entry_1);
  tv1.setText("Whatever goes here");
  ...
  // and so on for each column
  table.addView(tr);
}
```

The above worked for me when moving that same code into a class which extends TableRow did not.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had same issue, and figured it out, so maybe this will help future users.

The problem is, that when you inflate the TableRow from XML, and you add it ino your extended TableRow, it is seen by the Table as a single column, with multiple children, as the TableRow in your Layout is in essence a ViewGroup. Therefore it lays out the table, as a single column table.

The solution is that in the TableRow XML layout, use a `<merge>` type, rather than a `<TableRow>` type. This way when inflated, the items within your xml, will be merged into your extended TableRow, and your extended TableRow will have multiple colums.

Here is the example code

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zonetablerow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zonerow_name"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="#ffcccccc"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zonerow_invcount"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#ffcccc00"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</merge>
```